# Mapquest multiple routes are plotting sequentially

Tags: mapquest

I have below code to render multiple routes with lat/longs in the incoming order.

```
  plotRoute(data, routeColor): any {
    const stops = this.getStops(data);
    this.plotMarkers(data);
    stops.forEach((stop) => {
      for (let i = 1; i < stop.length; i++) {
        const directions = L.mapquest.directions();
        this.setRouteLayer(directions, routeColor);
        directions.route({
          start: [stop[i - 1].latitude, stop[i - 1].longitude],
          end: [stop[i].latitude, stop[i].longitude],
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

The code works fine except, it draws the routes one at a time and which is confusing the User. 
I want all the routes to be plotted just once. I tried `direction.route({location:[]})` also by collecting the array of lat/longs which solves the problem of rendering at once. But, I lose my order of the points/stops and the final route is not what was actually expected. Hence, I must specify `start/end`.

Is there a way I could set an array of `lat/long` including `start/end` to the `direction/route`?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up a list of waypoints with the start and end locations. For example:

start: '350 5th Ave, New York, NY 10118',
end: 'One Liberty Plaza, New York, NY 10006',
waypoints: [ '366 Columbus Ave, New York, NY 10024', '881 7th Ave, New York, NY 10019']

Comment: The input is only in the form of lat/longs.

Comment: Replace the addresses with lat/lng and you should be good to go.

start: '39.77028,-105.02724',
end: '39.77055,-105.01204',
waypoints: [ '39.76682,-105.02295', '39.76685,-105.01636']